# Are there any quests that level the thief tree?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The entire tree. The Bards College has Warrior and Mage but is there a Thief quest? Other than hermaeus mora of course?

Comment: There is the Theif's guild in Riften.

Comment: @peper757 Thanks for missing the question. I'm asking about a quest that has a reward of a free levelup in all skills in the thief tree.

Comment: IIRC some of the Bard's college fetch quests will add levels. And of course there's the Oghma Infinium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only two quests that level the entire stealth tree are are [Finn's Flute](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Finn%27s_Lute) (+1 to all stealth skills) and [Discerning the Transmundane](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane), which allows you to use the Oghma Infinium to advance all skills in your stealth tree by 5 points.